# print vue component from string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

This example is not working, is there any solution or usage is illegal?

```js
Vue.component('hello', {
    template: '<span>Hello world!</span>'
})
Vue.component('foo', {
    data(){
        return {
            say_hello: '<hello></hello>'
        }
    },
    template: '<div v-html="say_hello"></div>'
})
```

Comment: if you add vueJS dependencies, anyone can see the issue being replicated and can offer help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not supported. The content of `v-html` is not processed by Vue, so no vue components, tags or bindings can be used there.

In general, if you see any markup outside of a template, it's an anti-pattern. And v-html is something you should use rarely and with a bad conscience :-)

Comment: Don't hesitate to accept the answer if it's useful !